# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why is options be undefined here? `DisplayThisArr` is filled from this ajax call but then I go to another function and make another ajax call to another api and use some of that data to add another property to `DisplayThisArr` and then I want to display the modded `DisplayThisArr` but for some reason I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined`.

for more indepth go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26284848/2593877) to the full question

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            1: { type: "string" },.
            2: { type: "string" },
            3: { type: "string" },
            4: { type: "string" },
            5: { type: "string" },
            6: { type: "string" },
            7: { type: "string" },
            propertyImAdding: { type: "number" },
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    transport: {
        read:
            function(options) {

            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://localhost:port/api/blah/blah',
              dataType: 'json',
              async: false,
              data: data,
              success: function(json) {
                    DisplayThisArr = json;
                    vM.getOtherData(); //Get another [] of json objects from another api and mod DisplayThisArr
                    options.success(DisplayThisArr); //Display the modified DisplayThisArr array
              }
            });//end ajax
        }//end function(options)
    }
})//End datasource
```

Comment: You should never, EVER, set `async` to false. Ever. It will block any interaction with your page until the resource returns whether that takes 5 ms or 5 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`success` is not a property of `options`. Based on what you seem to want to do, you need to have a separate function to display the contents of the array and call it in each of your `ajax` success handlers.

The fact that you set `async` to `false` shows a lack of understanding of how `ajax` works. `success` is a callback function that gets executed when the resource returns from the server, whenever that happens to be. If you need to make multiple requests to the server (rare but possible) the 'best' way to accomplish this is to put the 2nd `ajax` call in the success handler of the first:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myscript.php',
    success: function(resp) {
        //do stuff to the array based on response
        $.ajax({
            url: 'otherscirpt.php',
            success: function(data) {
                //do more stuff based on other response
                display(myArray);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Its REALLY best if you can just get all the data in one scoop, but sometimes memory constraints on the server that are out of your control will force it, and sometimes that data needs to come in order, but you do it as above by chaining callbacks, not by setting `async` to `false`.

Comment: Nope, `options` is not defined.

Comment: I assume (perhaps incorrectly) that options gets passed in during the Fn call, but `success` belongs to the object literal being passed as an argument to `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not defined because it is, may be (probably not, this is typical for content of `this` variable), out of scope of the function `success`. Try this way

```
function(options) {
    var optns = options;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://localhost:port/api/blah/blah',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: data,
      success: function(json) {
            DisplayThisArr = json;
            vM.getOtherData(); 
            optns.success(DisplayThisArr);
      }
    });//end ajax
}//end function(options)
```

Or you do not submit `options` on the call of function `read` ))

Comment: @Lost1 It means that `options` is not provided as argument to the function `read`

Comment: So, why would that be?

Comment: @Lost1 Lets starting from the beginning. Why do you think that `transport.read` should have any arguments at all? I do not see it in API
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid Do you have an example of this kind of usage?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read) Then Go to "set read as a function" in the middle of the page

Comment: @Lost1 Yes, but it does not have any arguments. It means that when framework is calling this function, it also, probably, does not submit any arguments to it. The only think that function is doing - returning options for the .ajax call. `The value configured via transport.read is passed to jQuery.ajax. This means that you can set all options supported by jQuery.ajax via transport.read except the success and error callback functions which are used by the transport.` It does not accept arguments, but returns options for .ajax

Comment: don't i have to do `options.success(DisplayThisArr);` to make the grid show the updated array of JSON objects?

Comment: @Lost1 I do not know, I have to study API for this. But even if you have to - you choose the wrong way to pass `options` there. Can you use it as property of the main object and than read it before calling .ajax function?